# Getting Route Location outside of the Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying add a custom styling to the active route inside the navigation component inside the dashboardlayout, but I am not able to get the current route inside the current component.

```
const Index = props => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <DashboardLayout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path='/earnings' component={Earnings} />
        <Route exact path='/comms' component={Comms} />
        <Route exact path='/rankings' component={Rankings} />
        <Route exact path='/ratings' component={Ratings} />
        <Route exact path='/ads' component={Ads} />
        <Route exact path='/settings' component={Settings} />
        <Route exact path='/ad/details' component={AdDetails} />
        <Route exact path='/ad/submit-sample' component={SubmitSample} />
        <Route exact path='/feedback' component={Feedback} />
      </DashboardLayout>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little component that looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = ({
  children,
  to,
  exact,
  onClick,
  className,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    path={to}
    exact={exact}
    children={({ match }) => (
      <Link
        // Assign class and active class name
        className={match ? `${className} act-link` : className}
        to={to}
        replace={match && to === match.path}
        onClick={(e) => {
          // Avoid clicking the current route
          if (!match || to !== match.path) {
            onClick(e);
          }
        }}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </Link>
    )}
  />
);
```

You can use it this way:

```js
const NavList = ({
  links,
  toggleOpened,
}) => (
  <ul className="main-menu">
    {
      links.map((link) => (
        <li
          key={link.name}
          className={link.className}
        >
          <NavLink
            className="icon-w"
            to={link.url}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.target.focus();
              toggleOpened(false);
            }}
          >
            <div className={`os-icon ${link.icon}`} />
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
);
```

Hope it helps